# StringBuilder and regex parsing

Tags: java, regex, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBuilder` object that I use to build one large string, separating the strings in the `StringBuilder` object using a `"\n"` character, how can I efficiently build a regex around that object without splitting the string and doing a loop?

For example say I have the below regex:

```
private static final regexPattern = "(([a-z[1-9]]+)||([1-9[a-z]]+))"
```

If I have this:

```
String[] myStringList = aStringList.split("\n");
```

I'm trying to build an effective regex using the regexPattern and each string in myStringList.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern + myStringList[i]);
```

Is there anyway to do this without splitting my stringBuilder into a loop and checking each and every string?  Can I somehow build a large pattern around the entire StringBuilder object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will build a big "OR" regex out of your input, pre-pending `regexPattern` to each part of the input string:

```
String bigRegex = "(" + regexPattern + aStringList.replace("\n", ")|(" + regexPattern) + ")";
```

Here's some code that shows what you get:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String aStringList = "foo\nbar\nbaz";
    String bigRegex = "(" + regexPattern + aStringList.replace("\n", ")|(" + regexPattern) + ")";
    System.out.println(bigRegex);
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile(bigRegex);
}
```

Output:

```
((([a-z[1-9]]+)||([1-9[a-z]]+))foo)|((([a-z[1-9]]+)||([1-9[a-z]]+))bar)|((([a-z[1-9]]+)||([1-9[a-z]]+))baz)
```

Comment: Is using a "\n" separator character an effective way of building a string if I'm trying to use it in a regex?

Comment: Not especially, but it would be convenient if you got your input from a file - editing and maintaining that file would be easy keeping each regex part on a separate line. I think you're on to a good idea here.